# access file when I am connected to his wi-fi network

Tags: wi-fi, networking, lan

I have an andriod device.Can I access files of another android device ? I am connected to his wi-fi network. if yes how??

Comment: Same way as with any other computer on the very same network: the other device needs to share them.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171659/android-to-android-file-explorer-using-wifi-direct/171663#171663

Answer (score 0):

There is a plethora of apps that are designed to do just that. Search the play store for “file sharing” and just pick one. Install it on both devices and you're in business.