# How top copy files from Android (8) to PC, when large number of files in folder?

Tags: file-transfer, mtp, usb-mass-storage

I recently bought a NAS to store family photos, and I've just realised that my phone (Pixel XL) no longer supports USB Mass Storage, but just MTP.

I've got about 7400 files in my DCIM folder, and it seems impossible to browse this folder properly in either Windows10 or Unbuntu.  Windows takes and age and then explorer.exe simply crashes.  Ubuntu also takes forever and isn't really usable.

Is there anything that can help here?  (I've seen solutions using debugging mode but, is there a 'normal' solution?)

Thanks

Comment: No root unfortunately :(

Comment: Try any of these: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/200044/209414